# How to Persist Order with Cart Items in JAVA EE JPA, Order is with multiple items

Tags: java, sql, database, jpa, jpql

**Dataccess layer - to save an item in the database, it's going in catch exception**

I have added the models and persistent layer as well but it's not adding order due to some reason but, all values that are required are not null and have values

I do have it as list

and fetch type is eager

each order can have multiple items and the order number and oi item ref no are auto 
generated in the main app code

```
public void Add(Orders order) {

    EntityManager em = DBUtil.getEmFactory().createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction trans = em.getTransaction();

    try {

        Provinces prov = order.getShipProvince();
        prov.getOrdersList().add(order);

        User user = order.getCustomer();
        user.getOrdersList().add(order);

        Item item = new Item();
        List<OrderItem> list = order.getOrderItemList();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            item = list.get(i).getItem();
            item.getOrderItemList().add(list.get(i));
        }

        trans.begin();

        em.persist(order);

        trans.commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        trans.rollback();
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }

}
```

```
package models;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Orders.findAll", query = "SELECT o FROM Orders o")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Orders.findByOrderNumber", query = "SELECT o FROM Orders o WHERE o.orderNumber = :orderNumber")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Orders.findByShipfname", query = "SELECT o FROM Orders o WHERE o.shipfname = :shipfname")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Orders.findByShiplname", query = "SELECT o FROM Orders o WHERE o.shiplname = :shiplname")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Orders.findByPhone", query = "SELECT o FROM Orders o WHERE o.phone = :phone")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Orders.findByOrderDate", query = "SELECT o FROM Orders o WHERE o.orderDate = :orderDate")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Orders.findByShipDate", query = "SELECT o FROM Orders o WHERE o.shipDate = :shipDate")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Orders.findByShipAddress", query = "SELECT o FROM Orders o WHERE o.shipAddress = :shipAddress")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Orders.findByShipCity", query = "SELECT o FROM Orders o WHERE o.shipCity = :shipCity")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Orders.findByShipPostalCode", query = "SELECT o FROM Orders o WHERE o.shipPostalCode = :shipPostalCode")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Orders.findByShipCost", query = "SELECT o FROM Orders o WHERE o.shipCost = :shipCost")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Orders.findByShipCompany", query = "SELECT o FROM Orders o WHERE o.shipCompany = :shipCompany")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Orders.findByTrackingnumber", query = "SELECT o FROM Orders o WHERE o.trackingnumber = :trackingnumber")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Orders.findByOrderTotal", query = "SELECT o FROM Orders o WHERE o.orderTotal = :orderTotal")})
public class Orders implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Order_Number")
    private String orderNumber;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Ship_fname")
    private String shipfname;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Ship_lname")
    private String shiplname;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Phone")
    private String phone;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Order_Date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date orderDate;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Ship_Date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date shipDate;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Ship_Address")
    private String shipAddress;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Ship_City")
    private String shipCity;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Ship_Postal_Code")
    private String shipPostalCode;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Ship_Cost")
    private double shipCost;
    @Column(name = "Ship_Company")
    private String shipCompany;
    @Column(name = "Tracking_number")
    private String trackingnumber;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Order_Total")
    private double orderTotal;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "orderNumber", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<OrderItem> orderItemList;
    @JoinColumn(name = "Customer", referencedColumnName = "Email")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private User customer;
    @JoinColumn(name = "Ship_Province", referencedColumnName = "Province_ID")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Provinces shipProvince;

    public Orders() {
    }

    public Orders(String orderNumber) {
        this.orderNumber = orderNumber;
    }

    public Orders(String orderNumber, String shipfname, String shiplname, String phone, Date orderDate, Date shipDate, String shipAddress, String shipCity, String shipPostalCode, double shipCost, double orderTotal) {
        this.orderNumber = orderNumber;
        this.shipfname = shipfname;
        this.shiplname = shiplname;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.orderDate = orderDate;
        this.shipDate = shipDate;
        this.shipAddress = shipAddress;
        this.shipCity = shipCity;
        this.shipPostalCode = shipPostalCode;
        this.shipCost = shipCost;
        this.orderTotal = orderTotal;
    }

    public String getOrderNumber() {
        return orderNumber;
    }

    public void setOrderNumber(String orderNumber) {
        this.orderNumber = orderNumber;
    }

    public String getShipfname() {
        return shipfname;
    }

    public void setShipfname(String shipfname) {
        this.shipfname = shipfname;
    }

    public String getShiplname() {
        return shiplname;
    }

    public void setShiplname(String shiplname) {
        this.shiplname = shiplname;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public Date getOrderDate() {
        return orderDate;
    }

    public void setOrderDate(Date orderDate) {
        this.orderDate = orderDate;
    }

    public Date getShipDate() {
        return shipDate;
    }

    public void setShipDate(Date shipDate) {
        this.shipDate = shipDate;
    }

    public String getShipAddress() {
        return shipAddress;
    }

    public void setShipAddress(String shipAddress) {
        this.shipAddress = shipAddress;
    }

    public String getShipCity() {
        return shipCity;
    }

    public void setShipCity(String shipCity) {
        this.shipCity = shipCity;
    }

    public String getShipPostalCode() {
        return shipPostalCode;
    }

    public void setShipPostalCode(String shipPostalCode) {
        this.shipPostalCode = shipPostalCode;
    }

    public double getShipCost() {
        return shipCost;
    }

    public void setShipCost(double shipCost) {
        this.shipCost = shipCost;
    }

    public String getShipCompany() {
        return shipCompany;
    }

    public void setShipCompany(String shipCompany) {
        this.shipCompany = shipCompany;
    }

    public String getTrackingnumber() {
        return trackingnumber;
    }

    public void setTrackingnumber(String trackingnumber) {
        this.trackingnumber = trackingnumber;
    }

    public double getOrderTotal() {
        return orderTotal;
    }

    public void setOrderTotal(double orderTotal) {
        this.orderTotal = orderTotal;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<OrderItem> getOrderItemList() {
        return orderItemList;
    }

    public void setOrderItemList(List<OrderItem> orderItemList) {
        this.orderItemList = orderItemList;
    }

    public User getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(User customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    public Provinces getShipProvince() {
        return shipProvince;
    }

    public void setShipProvince(Provinces shipProvince) {
        this.shipProvince = shipProvince;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (orderNumber != null ? orderNumber.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Orders)) {
            return false;
        }
        Orders other = (Orders) object;
        if ((this.orderNumber == null && other.orderNumber != null) || (this.orderNumber != null && !this.orderNumber.equals(other.orderNumber))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "models.Orders[ orderNumber=" + orderNumber + " ]";
    }

}
```

```
package models;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;


@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Orders.findAll", query = "SELECT o FROM Orders o")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Orders.findByOrderNumber", query = "SELECT o FROM Orders o WHERE o.orderNumber = :orderNumber")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Orders.findByShipfname", query = "SELECT o FROM Orders o WHERE o.shipfname = :shipfname")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Orders.findByShiplname", query = "SELECT o FROM Orders o WHERE o.shiplname = :shiplname")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Orders.findByPhone", query = "SELECT o FROM Orders o WHERE o.phone = :phone")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Orders.findByOrderDate", query = "SELECT o FROM Orders o WHERE o.orderDate = :orderDate")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Orders.findByShipDate", query = "SELECT o FROM Orders o WHERE o.shipDate = :shipDate")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Orders.findByShipAddress", query = "SELECT o FROM Orders o WHERE o.shipAddress = :shipAddress")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Orders.findByShipCity", query = "SELECT o FROM Orders o WHERE o.shipCity = :shipCity")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Orders.findByShipPostalCode", query = "SELECT o FROM Orders o WHERE o.shipPostalCode = :shipPostalCode")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Orders.findByShipCost", query = "SELECT o FROM Orders o WHERE o.shipCost = :shipCost")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Orders.findByShipCompany", query = "SELECT o FROM Orders o WHERE o.shipCompany = :shipCompany")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Orders.findByTrackingnumber", query = "SELECT o FROM Orders o WHERE o.trackingnumber = :trackingnumber")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Orders.findByOrderTotal", query = "SELECT o FROM Orders o WHERE o.orderTotal = :orderTotal")})
public class Orders implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Order_Number")
    private String orderNumber;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Ship_fname")
    private String shipfname;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Ship_lname")
    private String shiplname;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Phone")
    private String phone;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Order_Date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date orderDate;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Ship_Date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date shipDate;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Ship_Address")
    private String shipAddress;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Ship_City")
    private String shipCity;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Ship_Postal_Code")
    private String shipPostalCode;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Ship_Cost")
    private double shipCost;
    @Column(name = "Ship_Company")
    private String shipCompany;
    @Column(name = "Tracking_number")
    private String trackingnumber;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Order_Total")
    private double orderTotal;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "orderNumber", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<OrderItem> orderItemList;
    @JoinColumn(name = "Customer", referencedColumnName = "Email")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private User customer;
    @JoinColumn(name = "Ship_Province", referencedColumnName = "Province_ID")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Provinces shipProvince;

    public Orders() {
    }

    public Orders(String orderNumber) {
        this.orderNumber = orderNumber;
    }

    public Orders(String orderNumber, String shipfname, String shiplname, String phone, Date orderDate, Date shipDate, String shipAddress, String shipCity, String shipPostalCode, double shipCost, double orderTotal) {
        this.orderNumber = orderNumber;
        this.shipfname = shipfname;
        this.shiplname = shiplname;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.orderDate = orderDate;
        this.shipDate = shipDate;
        this.shipAddress = shipAddress;
        this.shipCity = shipCity;
        this.shipPostalCode = shipPostalCode;
        this.shipCost = shipCost;
        this.orderTotal = orderTotal;
    }

    public String getOrderNumber() {
        return orderNumber;
    }

    public void setOrderNumber(String orderNumber) {
        this.orderNumber = orderNumber;
    }

    public String getShipfname() {
        return shipfname;
    }

    public void setShipfname(String shipfname) {
        this.shipfname = shipfname;
    }

    public String getShiplname() {
        return shiplname;
    }

    public void setShiplname(String shiplname) {
        this.shiplname = shiplname;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public Date getOrderDate() {
        return orderDate;
    }

    public void setOrderDate(Date orderDate) {
        this.orderDate = orderDate;
    }

    public Date getShipDate() {
        return shipDate;
    }

    public void setShipDate(Date shipDate) {
        this.shipDate = shipDate;
    }

    public String getShipAddress() {
        return shipAddress;
    }

    public void setShipAddress(String shipAddress) {
        this.shipAddress = shipAddress;
    }

    public String getShipCity() {
        return shipCity;
    }

    public void setShipCity(String shipCity) {
        this.shipCity = shipCity;
    }

    public String getShipPostalCode() {
        return shipPostalCode;
    }

    public void setShipPostalCode(String shipPostalCode) {
        this.shipPostalCode = shipPostalCode;
    }

    public double getShipCost() {
        return shipCost;
    }

    public void setShipCost(double shipCost) {
        this.shipCost = shipCost;
    }

    public String getShipCompany() {
        return shipCompany;
    }

    public void setShipCompany(String shipCompany) {
        this.shipCompany = shipCompany;
    }

    public String getTrackingnumber() {
        return trackingnumber;
    }

    public void setTrackingnumber(String trackingnumber) {
        this.trackingnumber = trackingnumber;
    }

    public double getOrderTotal() {
        return orderTotal;
    }

    public void setOrderTotal(double orderTotal) {
        this.orderTotal = orderTotal;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<OrderItem> getOrderItemList() {
        return orderItemList;
    }

    public void setOrderItemList(List<OrderItem> orderItemList) {
        this.orderItemList = orderItemList;
    }

    public User getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(User customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    public Provinces getShipProvince() {
        return shipProvince;
    }

    public void setShipProvince(Provinces shipProvince) {
        this.shipProvince = shipProvince;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (orderNumber != null ? orderNumber.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Orders)) {
            return false;
        }
        Orders other = (Orders) object;
        if ((this.orderNumber == null && other.orderNumber != null) || (this.orderNumber != null && !this.orderNumber.equals(other.orderNumber))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "models.Orders[ orderNumber=" + orderNumber + " ]";
    }

}
```

```
package models;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;


@Entity
@Table(name = "item")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Item.findAll", query = "SELECT i FROM Item i")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Item.findByUpsc", query = "SELECT i FROM Item i WHERE i.upsc = :upsc")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Item.findByName", query = "SELECT i FROM Item i WHERE i.name = :name")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Item.findByDescription", query = "SELECT i FROM Item i WHERE i.description = :description")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Item.findByCost", query = "SELECT i FROM Item i WHERE i.cost = :cost")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Item.findByRetailCost", query = "SELECT i FROM Item i WHERE i.retailCost = :retailCost")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Item.findByImageLink", query = "SELECT i FROM Item i WHERE i.imageLink = :imageLink")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Item.findByQuantity", query = "SELECT i FROM Item i WHERE i.quantity = :quantity")})
public class Item implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Upsc")
    private String upsc;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "Description")
    private String description;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Cost")
    private double cost;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Retail_Cost")
    private double retailCost;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Image_Link")
    private String imageLink;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Quantity")
    private int quantity;
    @JoinColumn(name = "Category", referencedColumnName = "Category_ID")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Category category;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "item", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<OrderItem> orderItemList;

    public Item() {
    }

    public Item(String upsc) {
        this.upsc = upsc;
    }

    public Item(String upsc, String name, String description, double cost, double retailCost, String imageLink, int quantity) {
        this.upsc = upsc;
        this.name = name;
        this.description =description;
        this.cost = cost;
        this.retailCost = retailCost;
        this.imageLink = imageLink;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public String getUpsc() {
        return upsc;
    }

    public void setUpsc(String upsc) {
        this.upsc = upsc;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public double getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    public void setCost(double cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public double getRetailCost() {
        return retailCost;
    }

    public void setRetailCost(double retailCost) {
        this.retailCost = retailCost;
    }

    public String getImageLink() {
        return imageLink;
    }

    public void setImageLink(String imageLink) {
        this.imageLink = imageLink;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<OrderItem> getOrderItemList() {
        return orderItemList;
    }

    public void setOrderItemList(List<OrderItem> orderItemList) {
        this.orderItemList = orderItemList;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (upsc != null ? upsc.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Item)) {
            return false;
        }
        Item other = (Item) object;
        if ((this.upsc == null && other.upsc != null) || (this.upsc != null && !this.upsc.equals(other.upsc))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "models.Item[ upsc=" + upsc + " ]";
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: when i try to persist it goes into catch and does not save data into the db, it's in Dataaccess layer

Comment: It goes into catch because of an error. What is it?

Comment: It doesn't show what is the error but it just goes in catch and rollback the transaction, i think the error is due to the cart items as they are connected but i cannot add anything into the order items table as order table has the parent value of order number

Comment: add `e.printStacktrace()`...

Comment: internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'Ship_Date' cannot be null
Error Code: 1048
Call: INSERT INTO orders (Order_Number, Order_Date, Order_Total, Phone, Ship_Address, Ship_City, Ship_Company, Ship_Cost, Ship_Date, Ship_Postal_Code, Ship_fname, Ship_lname, Tracking_number, Customer, Ship_Province) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
 bind => [15 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(models.Orders[ orderNumber=2003110202550000631 ])

Comment: But the shipdate can be  null

Comment: You've got it all there... That's your error

Comment: Thanks ill try to fix it

Answer (score 1):

There is an error thrown in the `catch` clause:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'Ship_Date' cannot be null Error Code: 1048 Call: INSERT INTO orders (Order_Number, Order_Date, Order_Total, Phone, Ship_Address, Ship_City, Ship_Company, Ship_Cost, Ship_Date, Ship_Postal_Code, Ship_fname, Ship_lname, Tracking_number, Customer, Ship_Province) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) bind => [15 parameters bound] Query: InsertObjectQuery(models.Orders[ orderNumber=2003110202550000631 ])

This means, that `Ship_Date` must have value upon insertion/update.

Comment: @007slayer no problem, consider upvoting the answer / marking as correct;>